# Mysql error 1136 Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I've been trying to export a table from excel to MySQL using the MySQL for Excel extension but I'm getting this error:

> Mysql error 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 Excel

My table has 21887 rows and 23 columns.

MySQL Workbench is opened and the database is connected.

This is the Excel export data screen and the settings:

[image: Error ocurred]

And this error occurs during the exporting:

[image: MySQL Excel plugin]

Comment: If It produces the INSERT script, can you share that

Comment: INSERT INTO `dados_municipios`.`localidades_2010` (...) VALUES (..., -61,9998238962936 , ...) 
Well, the problem seems to be de comma in numbers.  -61,9998238962936 instead of -61.9998238962936

Comment: Hmmm, due to the comma, it consider as two values. Hope the issue is solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel was using the comma symbol to separate decimal numbers and the MySQL Workbench was interpreting as two numbers, bacause of this the column count wasn't matching.

So I solved this casting the decimal numbers to string.

Answer (score 0):

column count doesn't match error appears because of mismatching number of columns in table schema and fields list.

in your case count number of columns in excel sheet and in your DB table, these must not be matching. add missing column in excel sheet and try again.